# React UI (ie. rendering of my app) not consistent with what's shown in inspect element

Tags: javascript, html, css, reactjs, tailwind-css

Weird problem here. I have a progress bar that looks like this:

```
1 export default function PercentageBar(props) {
2     return (
3         <div className="w-full h-1 my-1 bg-stone-200">
4             <div className={`h-1 bg-orange-500 w-[${props.percent}%]`} />
5         </div>
6     );
7 }
```

The styling is done via Tailwind CSS. If you're unfamiliar, basically what's happening is the outer div is as wide as the parent div, has a height of 1, margin on the top and bottom of 1, and is colored in a gray-ish tone. The inner div is then rendered on top of that, which also has a height of 1. The inner div is in orange and is as wide as `props.percent` (a percentage of the full width of the parent div).

I've verified that the `props.percent` is being passed in properly.

When `props.percent` changes at runtime dynamically, line 4 in particular sometimes acts weird (regardless of the percent passed in).

For example, if `props.percent` was equal to 48 and is now equal to 52, Inspect Element tells me that the line is

```
<div className={`h-1 bg-orange-500 w-[52%]`} />
```

which is correct. However, it's rendered like below (a full bar)

```
<div className={`h-1 bg-orange-500 w-[100%]`} />
```

Furthermore, sometimes it's rendered like `props.percent` equals 0. This only happens after `props.percent` changed values.

I've tried doing hard refreshes, resetting caches, etc. but the problem persists sporadically and across different browsers. If I refresh enough, sometimes the problem doesn't appear. Any idea what's happening here? Much appreciated!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Found the answer! Thanks to Ed Lucas for pointing me in the right direction. He's right - you can't create class names dynamically in Tailwind. You can find the explanation on that [here](https://tailwindcss.com/docs/content-configuration#class-detection-in-depth).

However, using the style tag that Ed suggested didn't work for me. Instead, what I did was I created a new function containing a switch statement that returns unbroken strings of class names for each width value. In other words:

```
function getWidthClassName(percent) {
    switch (percent) {
        case 0:
            return 'w-[0%]';
        case 1:
            return 'w-[1%]';
        case 2:
            return 'w-[2%]';
        ...
        case 99:
            return 'w-[99%]';
        case 100:
            return 'w-[100%]';
        default:
            return 'w-[0%]';
    }
}
```

Then, my progress bar looked like this:

```
export default function PercentageBar({percent}) {
    let widthClassName = getWidthClassName(percent);
    return (
        <div className="w-full h-1 my-1 bg-stone-200">
            <div className={`h-1 bg-orange-500 ${widthClassName}`} />
        </div>
    );
```

This works because instead of dynamically constructing class names at runtime, we now instead construct them statically. Tailwind is happy and we're happy.

Answer (score 0):

I have same the similar problem but with the `classNames` to tackle this i have sent the `classNames` from where i'm using `component` this ensure that `component` will re-render when props changes and I have also sent `!` `important` keyword is anything changing your class. Hope this will resolve your issue.

```
export default function PercentageBar({witdhPercentage}) {
    return (
        <div className="w-full h-1 my-1 bg-stone-200">
            <div className={`h-1 bg-orange-500 ${witdhPercentage}`} />
        </div>
    );
}
```

```
<PercentageBar witdhPercentage={`!${w-[${props.percent}%]}`} />
```

Answer (score 0):

If you are using Tailwind 3 (or Tailwind 2 in JIT mode), you cannot create classes dynamically, since they will not be included in the final CSS.

For your variable value, you might consider using a `style` prop instead to set the width. For example:

```
<div style={{width: `${props.percent}%`}} className={'h-1 bg-orange-500'} />
```